# Bind column value to a TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to bind the value returned from a SQL Query to a Text Box:

```
 protected void cmbPujaName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pujaselectedid = null;

        pujaselectedid = cmbPujaName.DataValueField;

        SqlConnection con2 = null;
        con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRKBSDB"].ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter pamt = new SqlDataAdapter("select Amount from PoojaDietyMaster where PoojaDietyMasterID =" + cmbPujaName.DataValueField, con2);
        DataSet pamtds = new DataSet();
        pamt.Fill(pamtds);
        //cmbPujaName.DataSource = pamtds;
        txtAmount.Text = pamtds -- Not sure what to add here
        txtAmount.DataBind();
    }
```

Please help

Comment: You'd want to get a specific string from your dataset. I don't believe you can set a `textbox.text` equal to a dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txtAmount.Text=pamtds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Amount"].ToString();

  make sure the field names in the select result have 'Amount' column in it..!!
```

**remove this code**

```
 txtAmount.DataBind();
```

Comment: @rajiv: so happy that my answer helped u..!! :)

Answer (score 3):

add this
`txtAmount.Text=pamtds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Amount"].ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

you can set `TextBox` to one particualr cell value from `DataSource` as below:

```
txtAmount.Text=pamtds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand("select Amount from PoojaDietyMaster where PoojaDietyMasterID =" + cmbPujaName.DataValueField,con2);
 double c1 = (double)c.ExecuteScalar(); 
 txtAmount.Text = c1.ToString();
```

Since you are just getting one value. Theres no need to load it to a Datatable